# How to create application to launch wine and Windows application

Tags: macos, .app

I'm trying to use "wine" on MAC osX Sierra version 10.12, wine is version 1.9.19

In the terminal I can launch Windows applications, however its a pain to have to keep typing in:

```
    /Applications/Wine\ Staging.app/Contents/MacOS/wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/HeidiSQL/heidisql.exe
```

I've searched around for a post on how to create shortcuts/applications to add to the launchpad, but so far none of the information has led me to a working end result.  Either the locations of wine is different or it just doesn't work.

I've tried creating an application script:

```
    do shell script "/Applications/Wine Staging.app/Contents/MacOS/wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/HeidiSQL/heidisql.exe"
```

But this won't run either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, in the end I created scripts which reside in my home folder:

Launch vi, create a file called HeidiSQL, insert:

```
    wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/HeidiSQL/heidisql.exe
```

Save and exit file, grant file execute permissions:

```
    chmod +x HeidiSQL
```

Launch wine terminal and type in ./HeidiSQL to launch, I then did the same for PSPad.exe:

```
    wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/PSPad\ editor/PSPad.exe
```

Comment: Anyone find a way to get the above wine script as a launcher shortcut thing? I have had no success with the script editor, cant figure out what it is or how to use it to create the equivalent of running ~/HeidiSQL in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a little old but I was just looking for something like this to launch HeidiSQL and I came up with these three solutions which I have tried and all of them work. I am putting my findings down here for it may help someone:

Wineskin (http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com), Playonmac (https://www.playonmac.com/en) and Winebottler 
 (http://winebottler.kronenberg.org)

Wineskin is a mac app that download and install (and manages, updates, etc) "wine" for you. It then creates a HeidiSQL.app (any name you want with any icon you want - but you need to configure it) around the windows.exe that includes the wine version selected and is completely self contained (does not need wine installed separately). Personally this is the neatest solution and my preferred even though there its a little more technical than Playonmac and similar to Winebottler. You need to read the instructions (which are very good) and you have choices to make as to the wine version to use and to configure the app. Noteworthy is that you need to change the windows version to XP rather than 7 or some buttons won't work.

Playonmac on the other hand is very user friendly. It has HeidiSQL listed on its website as compatible and its almost a single click install. You just select HeidiSQL from the list of programs and it will download everything you need for you. The only reason I prefer Wineskin is that it does not create a true self contained HeidiSQL.app. You can create a shortcut for it in your Applications folder but this will launch Playonmac and the app needs to be installed inside Playonmac. On the plus side, Playonmac will chose all the right settings for you to run the app correctly, the correct windows and wine version etc which is something you need to fiddle with with with Wineskin.

Winebottler again makes an app like Wineskin. The only real difference I could see is that with Wineskin the configuration app is actually part of the package whereas in Winebottler you have to recreate the package each time you make a change. I stuck with Wineskin. YMMV.